# Android Combine ImageDownload with CursorLoader

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-loadermanager, android-cursor, android-loader

I am using a very simple CursorLoader with an ImageDownloader. The ImageDownloader is running and everything but the CursorLoader finishes, and THEN the ImageDownloader begins its job of downloading the images, but the GridView is not updating with the downloaded images..

Within my ListFragment I have the following **onActivityCreated** method:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityCreated");

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    cursorAdapter = new OURSVPImageAdapter(getActivity(), null);

    // set the adapter on the gridview
    mGridView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

    // load the data
    getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(2, null, this);
}
```

My CursorLoader is as follows:

```
public static final class PhotoCursorLoader extends SimpleCursorLoader {

    Context mContext;

    public PhotoCursorLoader(Context context) {
        super(context);

        Log.d("PhotoCursorLoader", "Constructor");

        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor loadInBackground() {
        Log.d("PhotoCursorLoader", "loadInBackground");

        PhotosDataSource datasource = new PhotosDataSource(mContext);

        # STEP 1
        return datasource.getAllPhotos(((EventActivity) mContext).getEventId());
    }

}
```

The line labeled **# STEP 1** that retrieves all of the photos is just a method that retrieves a Cursor, as seen here:

```
public Cursor getAllPhotos(long event_id) {
    Log.d(TAG, "getAllPhotos");

    Cursor mCursor = getWritableDatabase().query(true, TABLE_NAME, COLUMNS_PHOTOS, DatabaseConstants.KEY_EVENT_ID + "=" + event_id, 
            null, null, null, null, null);

    return mCursor; 
}
```

So, this being the CursorLoader for the ListFragment, it assumes its complete when that Cursor is returned, which is correct. From my understanding the **setAdapter()** method is what would actually trigger the **getView** method.

The Trouble I'm having is that Everything seems to be running fine, my log output is outputting the urls for the images correctly, breakpoints all showing legit data, **the issue though, is that my grid view never gets updated with the images that the ImageDownloader retrieves.**

**EDIT**
This is the `SimpleCursorLoader` I'm using: https://gist.github.com/1217628

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with another of my questions.. the refresh shouldn't be forced, and when using a provider you can have the provider notify the contentresovler of updates. I have a method that inserts new photos, and that method uses the data provider. The data provider needed to

```
getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
```

to actually update the Cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Once again, the problem is most likely that you are managing your `Fragment`'s loaders from the parent `Activity`. The `Activity` and `Fragment` lifecycles do not sync with each other (at least not in a predictable manner), so your attempts at debugging the issue aren't actually getting you anywhere. The easiest way to guarantee predictable behavior is to have each separate component make use of its own `LoaderManager` (as opposed to having your `Fragment`s access `getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager()`).

Comment: I think one of the major differences in what you're used to, and what my code is doing, is that I'm using ActionbarSherlock.. which uses the support library.. the @Overrides and methods aren't available sometimes.. like.. I have to use getSupportLoaderManager NOT getLoaderManager..

Comment: It works the same with `ActionBarSherlock`. As long as you are consistent in using the same `LoaderManager` implementation (whether it is from the support library or the official Android SDK), my point still holds. I've changed `getLoaderManager` to `getSupportLoaderManager` in my answer, nonetheless.

Comment: *The Activity and Fragment lifecycles do not synced with each other*  and a text from the android developer site: *The lifecycle of the activity in which the fragment lives directly affects the lifecycle of the fragment, such that each lifecycle callback for the activity results in a similar callback for each fragment. For example, when the activity receives onPause(), each fragment in the activity receives onPause().* ?

Comment: @Rabbott (You know that it is the same thing because all of the SherlockFragments/SherlockActivitys are subclasses of the Fragment/Activity/FragmentActivity... Jake Wharton doesn't touch the `LoaderManager`s at all in the actual library... he simply inherits from the Android SDK/support library.

Comment: @Luksprog I agree that the `Activity` "directly affects the lifecycle of the `Fragment`". However, this does not mean they are in sync with each other. For example, the `Activity` could be created at any time between the `Fragment`'s `onCreate` and `onActivityCreated` methods... there is no way to know for sure. This is why methods like `onActivityCreated` exist... because otherwise there would be no way of knowing when the underlying `Activity`'s `onCreate` method has finished executing.

Comment: `Loader`s are started, stopped, destroyed, and retained across a single component's lifecycle. When one component begins to assume that `Loader`s from a separate component exist (and have been properly loaded), you will most likely run into trouble. For this reason, I would recommend having each component making use of its own `LoaderManager` instance.